# Differentiable in real analysis problem

Tags: real-analysis, differential

Let $f$ be a real value function that is differentiable in $[a,b]$, with [image].

Show that there is exists $x_0$ in $(a,b)$ such that:

[image]

I don't know how to prove it. Please, could anyone give me a hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's almost certainly "show there's an $x_0 \in [a, b]$ rather than $[a. v]$.

But the hypotheses seem to have a problem. If $f(a) = f(b) = 0$ and $f$ is everywhere differentiable, then $f'(c) = 0$ for some $c \in (a, b)$ by Rolle's Theorem. Yet you've got a hypothesis that says $f'(x) \ne 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.

I'd carefully check that your problem is stated correctly.

As stated, the problem's easy: a false hypothesis implies any conclusion.

Comment: i think the hypotheses $f'(x) \ne 0$ is wrong, i will edit the problem

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say that the hypotheses might say $f'(a) = f'(b) = 0$ (note the primes), and that $f'(x) \ne 0$ for *some* $x \in (a, b)$. With those hypotheses (or something like them), this becomes a mean-value-theorem problem, probably best solved by saying "suppose that $f'(x)$ is less than the given value for all $x$; then how large can $f(b) - f(a)$ be?" i.e., by contradiction. You'll probably need the fundamental theorem or the MVT *twice* to finish the problem, but that's all just a guess, since I don't know what the actual problem *is*.